# Track link click using nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to track the link clicked by the user in the email. All these links are external link.
To implement this, I will replace all the links to route via a nginx which I have set up, nginx access_log will log the activity and finally nginx will redirect the user to the target website.

```
/redirect/target_url=https://example.com..
```

I thought of few approach, example:
Redirecting to the original link:

```
location /redirect/{
   #access log will be generate which I can use for analytics
   return 301 $arg_target_url;
}
```

However, 301 is a permanent redirect and the browser cache will directly navigate the target_url instead of routing the request via /redirect which I have set up to track the activity.

Answer (score 1):

You might use HTTP 307, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307

Be aware though that you are opening yourself up to an Open Redirect Vulnerability: https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-an-open-redirection-vulnerability-and-how